# If 2 rows have the same ID select one with the greater other column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulty getting my head round this one, which should be simple.

When selecting from the table, if multiple rows have the same ID then select the row which has a greater value in Col2.

Here is my sample table:

```
ID      | Col2 | 
----------------
123     | 1    | 
123     | 2    | 
1234    | 2    | 
12345   | 3    |
```

Expected output:

```
ID      | Col2 | 
----------------
123     | 2    | 
1234    | 2    | 
12345   | 3    |
```

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY combined with MAX().

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Col2 DESC)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this example, `group by` is sufficient;

```
select id, max(col2) as col2
from t
group by id;
```

If you want the *row* with the maximum column, then I would often recommend `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

However, the "old-fashioned" method might have better performance:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 = (select max(t2.col2) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS operator can also be used:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 'Anything' FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE t1.id = t2.id
    AND t1.Col2 < t2.col2
)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e1d6/3

```
|    ID | Col2 |
|-------|------|
|   123 |    2 |
|  1234 |    2 |
| 12345 |    3 |
```